# Error Control Operators for call_user_func_array

Tags: php, function

I am calling `json_encode` function using `call_user_func_array`function.

This is my code

```
call_user_func_array( 'json_encode', $data );
```

I want to suppress warning errors thrown by `json_encode` so i put suppression operator in front of  `call_user_func_array` like this

```
@call_user_func_array( 'json_encode', $data );
```

My question is will it suppress error thrown by `json_encode` ? or doesn't work?
if it will not work how can i suppress it?

Comment: What warning is displayed? I propose you react on it instead suppressing it.

Comment: From the _php.net_ manual: Warning
Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to why.

Comment: I am converting data into utf-8 some time it cannot be process so i want to avoid that warning ...

Comment: Way you call json_encode function by call_user_func_array?

Comment: json_encode function does not encode non utf-8 character so... first i will check json_encode work or not ... if not work then i will convert data non utf-8 character in to utf-8 character then i will call json_encode function... so first check if warning display i want to suppress it @Naumov

Comment: call_user_func() yuo can use this function. And get data as utf-8 character set not realy in begining, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the second argument within `call_user_func_array` like as

```
call_user_func_array( 'json_encode', $data );//assuming the second parameter to be array
```

then it'll throw warning

> Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be integer, array given in

so in order to get it work without suppressing an error you need to use it like as

```
call_user_func_array( 'json_encode', array(&$data) );
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/DZTc0)

Comment: $data variable is a array like this $data=array( $arg1 , $arg2 );

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to temporary suppress WARNINGS (and maybe NOTICES), but let all other messages be shown. Something like this:

```
        $save_erep = error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);
        $result = call_user_func_array( 'json_encode', array($data) );
        error_reporting($save_erep);
```

Oh, and look at the *array($data)* construct. It might suppress warnings anyway.

Comment: your answer is ok ..what will happen if it like this @call_user_func_array( 'json_encode', $data );

Comment: As the _php.net_ manual website says: "...will even disable error reporting for critical errors...". I'm quite sure that this is **not** what you want. Best would be to eliminate the cause of the warning. I.e. provide the parameters as expected according to the function interface:  _array($data)_, or _array(&$data)_ when $data must be modified. You then will get no warning. And, the function in most cases does not work correctly with wrong call parameters anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need use call_user_func()

```
call_user_func('json_encode', $data);
```

because call_user_func_array() transparent each element as parameter function for example:

```
$data = array(1,2);
call_user_func_array('json_encode',$data); // equivalent json_encode(1,2);
```

Comment: call_user_func_array('json_encode',$data); this is what i want

Comment: sorry but way in this contest call_user_func_array() bad functio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That would work. You can test it like this:

This generates a warning:

```
trigger_error('test', E_USER_WARNING);
```

This generates a warning:

```
call_user_func_array('trigger_error', ['test', E_USER_WARNING]);
```

This does not generate a warning:

```
@trigger_error('test', E_USER_WARNING);
```

This does not generate a warning:

```
@call_user_func_array('trigger_error', ['test', E_USER_WARNING]);
```

It’s obviously better to prevent warnings rather than suppress them. I used this solution to suppress the useless warning "Warning: ftp_fput(): Successfully transferred...".